# Limit of Riemannian manifolds is not Riemannian

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I want to prove that $D$, standard unit ball in ${\bf R}^2$ with $|\ |$, with a metric $\| \ \|_1$ is a limit of Riemannian manifolds $X_i$. Here problem is to find $X_i$

(If necessary, all metrics in here is **strictly intrinsic**)

**Proof** : $Y:=\{ (x,y)| x$ or $y$ is an integer$\}$ has a metric $d=\|\ \|_1$ : $$d((a,b),(x,y))=|a-x| + |b-y|$$

Then $$ \lim_i \ \bigg(Y,\frac{1}{i} d\bigg)=({\bf R}^2,\|\ \|_1)$$

( This is followed from **asymptotic cone** : Asymptotic cone of a metric space $(X,d)$ is $\lim_{t>0,\ t\rightarrow 0} \ (X,td)$ )

**Definition of limit of metric space** : $(X_i=X,d_i)$ is a metric space Then $(X,d)$ is a limit if $$ {\rm sup}_{x,\ x'\in X} \ |d_i(x,x')-d(x,x')| \rightarrow 0 $$

But $Y$ is a not Riemannian manifolds (Not smooth) But from this we consider $g_n$ in ${\bf R}^2$ : On $Y$, $g_n$ conincides to standard inner product $g$ and $g_n$ is strictly larger then $g$ on ${\bf R}^2-Y $

That is consider a function : If $d_n$ is a metric from $ng$, define $$ f_n(p):=d_{ng}(p,Y)^{2n} $$

If $F_n\geq 0$ with $|f_n-F_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ is smooth, then define $$ g_n = \frac{g+F_ng}{n^2} $$

Here I have a question : $g_n$ is smooth ? (That is, it is a Riemannian metric)

And we must show that $d_{g_n}\rightarrow \|\ \|_1$ By construction, in $g_n$, one coordinate of **shortest path** from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is close to an integer and its length is close to $\frac{2}{n}$.

Here $(x,y)\in D$ is corresponded to $(nx,ny)$ in $X_n={\bf R}^2$. I believe that $X_\infty$ is $({\bf R}^2,\|\ \|_1)$. So why do we consider $D$ not ${\bf R}^2$ ?

My idea is right ? Thank you in anticipation
(reference : A course in metric geometry - D. Burago, Y. Burago, and S. Ivanov 248p. exe 7.1.3)

Comment: I find the question to be a bit confusing. How exactly do you define the limit of a sequence of riemannian manifolds ?

Comment: I see I will add definition

Comment: So your question is whether the Manhattan metric can be expressed as the limit of metrics that are induced by riemannian metrics ?

Comment: Yes (Manhattan=one norm $\|\ \|_1$). So limit is not Riemannian.

Comment: What exactly is your reasoning behind the fact that $||.||_1$ is not induced by a riemannian metric ? Is it because the shortest path between two given points is not necessarily smooth ?

Comment: $(D,\| \ \|_1)$ is not $2$-dimensional Riemannian since there exists infinitely many shortest paths between any two close points.

Comment: When you are talking about a metric that is not induced by a riemannian metric, how exactly to you define a shortest path between two points ? Strictly speaking, one cannot associate a reasonable "lenght" to a given curve in terms of an arbitrary metric on R^n.

Comment: Let $c(t)$ be a path between $c(0)=a$ and $c(1)=b$ Define a length $l(c):=\inf_P \sum_{i=1}^n d(c(t_i),c(t_{i+1}) )$ where $P$ is a partition If $l(c)=d(a,b)$, then $c$ is shortest. And I can not understand "cannot associate"

Comment: You are right. I forgot about the intrinsic definition of path lenght. My apologies.